# Integrate over an area of a parabola

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How do I figure out the integral bonds for **r** when integrating over the area M under a parabola **y=2-x^2**?

[image]

Do I need to solve a quadratic equation? I think there must be an easier solution.

[image]

**Clarification**

I want to calculate the following integral using polar coordinates (in this order).

$\iint_Mf(r,\varphi)drd\varphi$

Comment: Why in the world are you trying to use polar coordinates?

Comment: Are you confusing integration over a circle with integration bounded by a paraboloid (if I was doing this problem, I would avoid polar integration

Comment: @TedShifrin Because they told us to use polar coordinates in an exam :D

Comment: @SinaBabaeiZadeh Right ... but they wanted us to use polar coordinates in an exam. I have added a clarification because it wasn't clear what exactly I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume that you have an integrand which is awkward in cartesian coordinates but OK in polar coordinates so that you want to perform the integration in polar coordinates. At the boundary, $r\sin\phi=2-r^2\cos^2\phi$ so by the quadratic formula
$$\begin{align}r&=\frac{-\sin\phi\pm\sqrt{\sin^2\phi+8\cos^2\phi}}{2\cos^2\phi}\\
&=\frac{\sin^2\phi-\sin^2\phi-8\cos^2\phi}{2\left(-\sin\phi\mp\sqrt{\sin^2\phi+8\cos^2\phi}\right)\cos^2\phi}=\frac4{\sin\phi+\sqrt{\sin^2\phi+8\cos^2\phi}}\end{align}$$
Where we have taken the upper signs because we want $r>0$. Thus
$$\int_{-\sqrt2}^{\sqrt2}\int_0^{2-x^2}f(x,y)\,dy\,dx=\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\frac4{\sin\phi+\sqrt{\sin^2\phi+8\cos^2\phi}}}f(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)r\,dr\,d\phi$$

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to convince myself that nobody would put such a thing in an exam and there must be a simpler solution. I was wrong.

Comment: BTW do you know if the solution would be easier if the parabola would be y=4-x^2 instead?

Comment: Can't believe all the typos! It would probably be easier in cartesian coordinates because there would be no square root in the limits, but it doesn't look like it would make much difference in polar coordinates.